# Как реализовать регистрацию в приложении с заданными полями?

Tags: android

Где почитать информацию или взять исходники о том, как реализовать регистрацию в приложении с заданными полями?

При первом запуске пользователь регистрируется, вводит страну, город, Фио, телефон и пароль (дважды). Данные, допустим, отправляются в базу MySql на хостинг. После успешной регистрации пользователь вводит номер телефона и пароль в новом окне и входит в приложение (видит новое окно "Добро пожаловать!", к примеру).

Comment: Слишком обширный вопрос. Скорей всего никто не ответит, ну или в лучшем случае отправят на фриланс-биржу=) "Где почитать информацию" - погуглите, мне кажется найдется более 1000 страниц с результатом. "как реализовать регистрацию в приложении с заданными полями?" - прочитайте про верстку xml. Тут нет ничего сложного

Comment: Рекомендую зайти на фриланс сайт с вопросом, "сколько" будет стоить "это сделать"

Comment: Вы бы еще спросили *Как сделать приложение*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [здесь](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) все подробно описано и реализовано. Удачи!

P.s. Я бы выписал все основное, честно, Но там все основное и много нюансов. Ссылка не удалится, сайт, который приведен обновляется по сей день. Прошу не удалять ответ! :)